# Execute Multiple commands using same shell with simple ssh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I have to execute multiple commands in the same ssh shell in node js. I am using simple-ssh for this. But the execution stops due to the sudo case.

The below code has four commands that I needed to execute in the same ssh. The execution stops after the command switch user to root. I cannot execute the third command in separate ssh as the commands cd and switch user will not be executed in the new ssh.

```
   var cmd = 'cd /home/sample/test/core/build/bin/' + "\n" + 'sudo su root' 
   + "\n" + 'su test' + "\n" + './app'
   ssh.exec(cmd, {
        pty: true,
        out: function (stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        },
        err: function (stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    }).start();
```

I want to execute the four commands with the same ssh. Is there a way that I can achieve? I am also comfortable with moving from simple-ssh to any other npm that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which npm module you are using. But you can achieve this by using [ssh2shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2shell)

This takes array of commands as an argument

`commands:["cd /home/sample/test/core/build/bin/", "sudo su root", "su test", "./app"]`

Happy scripting!

Comment: Hi Vimal, the shell closes when all the commands are finished executing, which is a problem for me because i am running a application which also closes.. How to make it wait or keep the session for particular time? - @Vimal Mahi

Comment: @VenkatMano - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-promise seems to work for autoconnection, but not sure if we can pass multiple commands in exec(). Please have a look.

Comment: I found a solution for starting the application in the background. And also there is an idle timeout in ssh2shell that can wait for the time specified before closing the terminal.

Comment: @VenkatMano - Happy to help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *sudo su root* will create a new shell (and su test) and it will therefor not receive the sequence of statements.
Try encapsulating with double qoutes in combination with -c

```
maarten@Mint19:~$ cat su_test.sh 
sudo sh -c "cd /home ; du -s * | sort -rn > USAGE"
```